# Python Determining if an index in a list exists

Tags: python, list

I am creating a small program that allows the user to enter a string into an index of their choosing in a list. If the user specifies to enter their string into index 2, and there is already a value, then the program should delete the current value and replace it with the new one. If the index the user specifies does not exist, the program should insert the index into the list. However, I don't know how to test to see if an index exists without it throwing an error.
This is my specific code:

```
if myDict["List"][user_index] is None:
    myDict["List"].insert(user_index, user_string)
else:
    myDict["List"][user_index] = user_string
```

I get this error when checking if myDict["List"][user_index] exists:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Your'e asking about a list but your code suggests a dictionary. Edit your questions so it's clearer what type `myDict` is.

Comment: @DeepSpace I think the question is clear as it is. `myDict` is a dict, `myDict["List"]` is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
if index >= 0 and index < len(list):
    do_someting
```

But it is not optimized.

EDIT:
With a dict() it becomes:

```
if user_index not in myDict["List"]:
    myDict["List"].update(user_index, user_string)
else:
    myDict["List"][user_index] = user_string
```

Comment: Note that negative indexes also work (counting from the end) so technically you should test for `-len(list) <= index < len(list)`

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do. The index does not exist at all, yet I need to test if it exists somehow. That's the part I don't understand. I could use your suggestion if I was using a predefined list.

Comment: Or rather, I don't know whether or not a specific index, such as if mylist[731] exists; it needs to handle an arbitrary index, not just one in ascending order.

Comment: @andrewLalis what does you index represent ?
In this case you may need to use a dictionary like suggest by mescalium

Comment: The index represents where a user chose to place a string in a list. The user told the program to place string x at mylist[position y].

Comment: If it needs to handle an arbitrary index i without all the indices less than i existing, you probably want a dictionary, not a list. If you absolutely must use a list, I suppose you could fill up a list with Nones.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `myDict["List"]` a `dict()`, you don't have to worry about checking if it exist or not, just change it:

```
myDict["List"][user_index] = user_string
```

If the index does not exist, it will create a new entry in the dictionary, otherwise it will update the existing entry.

It will work as a "sparse" vector.

However, if later you need to turn the `dict` into a `list`, you can use this code:

```
myDict["List"] = [myDict["List"].get(k) for k in range(1+max(myDict["List"].keys()))]
```

Example:

```
>>> d={1: 'foo', 4: 'bar'}
>>> [d.get(k) for k in range(1+max(d.keys()))]
[None, 'foo', None, None, 'bar']
```

Comment: This still gives me an error: IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Because you are not using a `dict`. A dict never raises `IndexError`

Comment: To clarify, you need to initialize your "List" with: `myDict["List"] = dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be using dictionaries rather than lists.  A better way to find out whether a given key exists in a dictionary is like so...

```
if not user_index in myDict["List"]:
```

This assumes that you already know that myDict contains an entry for the key "List".

Comment: In this case, myDict["List"] refers to a list, and I just tested this and in the case that the index already exists, the code doesn't overwrite what is already there.